# UITextfield cursor disappears after an UIAlertView popup on IOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextfield, uialertview

I have a `UITextfield` who has the focus, the cursor is there. If the user press a button and the `UITextfield` is empty, I launch an `UIAlertView`. When the user press OK, the `UITextField` has still the focus but the cursor disappears.

The problem appears only on iOS7, not on iOS6.

How can I fix this bug ?

Edit for more info:

The `UITextField` is the first responder, it is not the problem, when I type, it works, but there is no cursor...

Comment: if I use resignFirstResponder, when I retake the focus on UITextField, the cursor doesn't appears

Comment: I've noticed a few occasions where the cursor isn't visible in a text field on iOS7 even when typing.

Answer (score 0):

You should make your text field first responder in the alert view delegate.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {   
 [myTextField becomefirstresponder];}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add text field's delegate in your .h file

```
-(void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

        //u need to change 0 to other value(,1,2,3) if u have more buttons.then u can check which button was pressed.

    if (buttonIndex == 0) {  //0 for Ok button index

      [self textFieldDidBeginEditing:yourTextFeild];


    }



}


- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    UITextPosition *beginning = [textField beginningOfDocument];
    [textField setSelectedTextRange:[textField textRangeFromPosition:beginning
                                                          toPosition:beginning]];
}
```

Comment: I already tried, the UITextField is the first responder, when I type, it works, but There is no cursor

Answer (score 0):

I also found the same issue in `ios 7`. Still don't know the reason, but maybe you should set the `tintcolor` property of `textfield`.

```
if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0"))
{
    [[UITextField appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
}
```

Comment: Works but all my buttons text become blue